# Read RDF N-Triples and replace them with a hashed index 'on the fly'

Tags: import, hashing

I want to process a 181GB uncompressed [RDF N-Triples](https://www.w3.org/TR/n-triples/) file. You may download a small [sample file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B43bDM6LmWjtQzJmS1h5dFdQUk0) (4KB) and read the file line by line.

```
ntFile = OpenRead["small.nt"];
line = ReadLine[ntFile];

While[line =!= EndOfFile,
   record = StringCases[line, {"<" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ ">" -> x, "\"" ~~ y__ ~~ "\"" -> y, "@" ~~ z__ ~~ " " -> z}];
   Print[record];
   line = ReadLine[ntFile]
];
```

So far so good, but now it comes the difficult part, (at least for me ;-) I want to replace each < http... > member of my `record` list with an index from a hash table.

```
(* Hash Table - e.g. for the first five lines of the text file you have
   1 http://example/astronomy.constellation.contains
   2 http://example/type.object.name
   3 http://example/type.property.expected_type
   4 http://example/astronomy.star
   5 http://example/type.property.schema
   6 http://example/astronomy.constellation
   7 http://example/rdf-syntax-ns#type
   8 http://example/type.property
   9 http://example/rdf-schema#Property
*)
```

The absolute requirement for such a task is that both the replacement and the creation of hash table must occur 'on the fly'.

An output of the first five records as it runs:

```
  (*
     {1, 2, "Stars", "en"}
     {1, 3, 4}
     {1, 5, 6}
     {1, 7, 8}
     {1, 7, 9}
  *)
```

#### What is the purpose of this processing ?

It will populate a database, possibly a graph database.

#### Perl Comparison

The solution in Perl, a friend of mine gave me some code, is 20 lines without spacing between. They define `%myhash` for hash table and then they have access to the table and the keys with the `$` symbol e.g. `$myhash`.

#### About Compression

I have also a question about compression. If the file is compressed as `gz` then it is about 30GB. Is it possible to read lines with Wolfram Language, how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a solution, it might not be the most efficient one, but it works. I had to learn about Reap/Sow first and how you export Mathematica code to markdown ;-)

```
ntFile = OpenRead["small.nt"];
line = ReadLine[ntFile];
$hash = <||> ;
hashcnt = 1;

While[line =!= EndOfFile,
  record = StringCases[line, {"<" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ ">" -> x, "\"" ~~ y__ ~~ "\"" -> y, "@" ~~ z__ ~~ " " -> z}]];

  ndxrec = record /. Reap[
      If[StringMatchQ[#, "http:" ~~ __],
         ndx = Lookup[$hash, #];
  If[MissingQ@ndx, 
            Sow[# -> hashcnt]; AppendTo[$hash, # -> hashcnt]; hashcnt++,
            Sow[# -> ndx]]
      ] & /@ record
  ][[2, 1]];

  (* Run as a script from command line to convert your nt file Or
     Add indexed record to the database .... *)
  Print[ndxrec];

  line = ReadLine[ntFile]
];

Close[ntFile];
```

### HashTable Output

```
$hash //Dataset
```

[image]

Comment: PS1: One way I am thinking to improve this solution is by reading big chunks of data from the file. But I have not done this before.


PS2: If you happen to know how to improve speed, memory efficiency, etc, or if you know the answer to my question about reading compressed files please advice or write your answer.


PS3: I am very happy that this Mathematica script is about the same length of code I saw in Perl :-)